# A nonlinear Gronwall estimate

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose one has the differential inequality

$$\frac{dx}{dt} \leq - x^2 + \phi(t) x^{\frac{1}{2}}, \qquad x(0) = 1,$$

where furthermore $\phi$ satisfies

$$ \int_0^t \phi(s) ds \leq x(t)^{\frac{1}{2}}, \qquad \phi(0) = 1$$

Is it true that $x$ remains finite for finite time?

Comment: Nice question (although not really well formulated since the square root is not defined for negative values). What did you try?

Comment: You should at least mention a reference to classical Gronwall lemma. Here is one : (https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Gronwall_lemma)